# How to delete/hide in IF-ELSE statment previouse statements in HTML

Tags: html

How can I make that so it will work only one condition at one time? Basically there is a time when A,B, and C can be pick at one time all of them. Example: So if you pick A there should be only one posibility and it is "else if (A != null)", but if there is A and B it should display only "else if (Model.B != null)", but if it is A,B, and C it should display only "else if (Model.SoldOut != null)". So is there any way to do that? Or is there any way to delete A when it display B, and delete A and B when it displays C?

```
            @if (A == null & B == null & C == null)
            {
                @Resources.Undefined;
            }
            else if (A != null)
            {
                @Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(Model.A.GetDisplayValue());
            }
            else if (Model.B != null)
            {
                @Model.B
            }
            else if (Model.SoldOut != null)
            {
                <p>-</p>
            }
```

Comment: Firstly, this is NOT an HTML question.  The flow control statements you're sharing look like C# Razer syntax.  Perhaps you should re-tag your question to that, or whatever language your logic is from.

Comment: Secondly, you're not doing a good job of describing the logic that's required, so it's incredibly hard for people to assist you in accomplishing the desired result.
<br/>Just a suggestion: instead of abstracting your logic into A, B, C, etc, make it concrete.  Name them what they actually represent, and I believe the human mind will have a far easier time working out the logic that's required.

Comment: That's not HTML. Please fix your tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by changing the order of else if statements

```
 @if (A == null & B == null & C == null)
 {
     @Resources.Undefined;
 }
 else if (Model.SoldOut != null)
 {
     <p>-</p>
 }
 else if (Model.B != null)
 {
     @Model.B
 }
 else if (A != null)
 {       
     @Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(Model.A.GetDisplayValue());
 }
```

Comment: Thank you that really worked

Answer (score 1):

My attempt at what you're describing is as follows.  It's an inversion of your logic.

```
// IF THEY'RE ALL PICKED
//   it should display only "else if (Model.SoldOut != null)"
@if(A && B && C)
{
    <p>-</p>
}

// it should display only "else if (Model.B != null)"
else if(A && B)
{
    @Model.B
}

// there should be only one posibility and it is "else if (A != null)"
else if(A)
{
  @Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(Model.A.GetDisplayValue());
}
else
{
  @Resources.Undefined;
}
```

But, like I said in my comment, it's incredibly difficult to figure out the logic when you're not describing all of the potential cases.   E.g. What if 'C' is the only one that's picked?  You know?